# I would like to run and debug the polymer-tutorial in the DartEditor

Tags: dart, dart-polymer, dart-editor

I would like to run and debug the polymer-tutorial ( https://www.polymer-project.org/docs/start/getting-the-code.html ) in the DartEditor but the code is not setup to do so. I am a beginner with DartEditor and Polymere. Can somebody help or provide a git repository? I had not much luck to get it working
Thx J

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As luck would have it, I recently ported that tutorial to Dart. In this Github repo, you'll find the starter files and a series of HTML files detailing the steps to take to complete it. It is slightly changed from the original tutorial, but it's very close.

https://github.com/montyr75/polymer_social_media_tutorial

Comment: Cool that is great - When I run it I get an empty page. I suspect this is the starting stage before going through the tutorial - right?

Comment: If somebody is interested I added a github repository which will have for each step of the tutorial a commit:
https://github.com/ride4sun/polymer_social_media_tutorial

The github mentioned above is the starting point.

Comment: That's correct. The starting state is mostly blank, and once you've done the steps, there is stuff to see.

Answer (score 2):

The repo you linked to is Polymer.js code (js for JavaScript), DartEditor is for Dart there is not much you can do with this code in DartEditor.

Comment: Somehow I thought Dart and Polymer are connected like C# and WPF.
Thx for the clarification.